# What are the most-significant bits set to when casting to a "larger" type?

Tags: c++, c, casting

In C/C++, when I perform the following cast:

```
uint8_t a = 0xAB;

//In C++
uint32_t b = static_cast<uint32_t>(a);

//In C
uint32_t c = (uint32_t)a;
```

I assume the most-significant bits of the "larger" type (`b`) are all zero.  Is this guaranteed by the standard when casting from a type with less bits to a type with more?

Comment: it would be rather broken if casting to a wider type would change the value. Please decide for one language

Comment: Protip: search for "sign-extension". And both C and C++ do not mandate any particular bitwise representation of integers, so (I believe, I might be wrong though) that setting _any_ bits in any standard integer-type values may be implementation-defined - I'll have to consult the spec.

Comment: If those extra bits weren't zeros, you'd have a different value.

Comment: 2's complement integers (i.e. signed ints) will extend the MSBit, so -1 int8_t will still be -1 when assigned to int32_t, not 255.

Comment: Depending how you interpret the "most significant bits". If they are real bits in the memory then it will depend on the endianness and type of the integer.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** The [language-lawyer] tag should not be edited into this question retroactively, after answers have been posted, as that tag changes the meaning of the question and thus what answers are considered suitable. Therefore, edits adding that tag have been rolled back. If you disagree with this assessment, post an answer to [this Meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423369/what-is-the-proper-usage-of-the-language-lawyer-tag). Do not re-tag this question. Engaging in an edit war on this question will result in your account being suspended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and C++ technical terminology differ a bit in this area.  I will use C terminology, but the ideas conveyed apply to both languages.

Type conversions such as those produced by C-style casts and C++ `static_cast`s are operations on values, not on objects, and their results are also values, not objects.  The *representations* of the operand and result values -- including the values of any particular bits -- are not addressed by the specifications for those operations.

Thus, the basic answer to your question is that **when applied to values of arithmetic type, these operations are value-preserving if the destination type can represent the operand value**.

With respect to your example, you ask ...

> I assume the most-significant bits of the "larger" type (b) are all zero. Is this guaranteed by the standard when casting from a type with less bits to a type with more?

In light of the (separate) specifications for representation of integer types, that the conversions are value-preserving means

- **For non-negative operands**, if the source and destination types are both integer types, and the destination type is represented with more value bits than the source type, then the value bits of a destination-type representation of the result that do not correspond to value bits in the source-type representation of the operand value will take the value 0.
- **For negative operands**, if the source and destination types are both (signed) integer types, and the destination type is represented *in two's complement form* with more value bits than the source type, then the value bits of a destination-type representation of the result that do not correspond to value bits in the source-type representation of the operand will take the value 1.  This is called "sign extension".

Answer (score 2):

The type `uint8_t` is unsigned integer type

```
uint8_t a = 0xAB;
```

So the value will be preserved when an object of this type is casted to the type `uint32_t` because objects of this type can accommodate the value `0xAB`.

Actually a casting is redundant. You may just write

```
uint32_t c = a;
```

You even may write

```
uint32_t a = 0xAB;
uint8_t c = a;
```

because again the value `0xAB` can be stored in an object of the type `uint8_t`.